# make insert one by one in order C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have an unsorted array list and I want to insert this array to my custom data structure one by one. When I create my insert function it went insert in order

test arr is {9,10,7,8,5,6,3,4,1,2};
list  after the insert  {1,3,5,7,9,10,8,6,4,2}
my insert function block

```
void  insert(value_type d)
{
  if (data.size() == 0)
  {
     data.push_back(d);
  }
  else if (data.size() > 0)
  {
    // get data begin 
    //std::list<value_type>::iterator iter = data.begin();
    for (auto iter = data.begin(); iter != data.end();++iter)
    {
      if(d > *iter)
      {
        data.push_back(d);
        break;
      }
      else if (d <= *iter)
      {
        data.insert(iter,d);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to insert them in sorted order, via a linear search.  Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: @MooingDuck this what I'm trying to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear you are trying to do the insertion of an insertion sort. The standard library has you covered:

Find where the new element should go in O(logn) - upper_bound is a binary search:

```
var pos = std::upper_bound(data.begin(), data.end(), d);
```

Insert the element there:

```
data.insert(pos, d);
```

Or even as a 1 liner for your whole function...

```
data.insert(std::upper_bound(data.begin(), data.end(), d), d);
```